# Line break goes outside of paragraph is it starts with an image

Tags: html, css

[image]

I'd like the second line of the text above to be in line with the first, as if they're in a paragraph

```
<img src="123.jpg"/>
Acquisto sicuro, pagamento in contanti alla consegna
```

I've tried to wrap the text in `<p>` but it breaks the line before the image. Also tried with `<span>` with both the text-only and the text+image, also with all possible attributes of the `display` (`block`, `inline`, ecc...) property. Still same result.

How do you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An (modern) option is to use a [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox).

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px; /* Just for demo purpose */
}

.container p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://www.fineartpixel.com/wp-content/uploads/edd/2018/01/THUMB_CartoonKidsHolding123Numbers.jpg" width="150" />
  <p>Acquisto sicuro, pagamento in contanti alla consegna</p>
</div>
```